# $f_n\rightarrow g$ in $L_1$ and $f_n\rightarrow h$ in $L_2$ .Then $g=h $almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$f_n\rightarrow g$ converges in $L_1$  and $f_n\rightarrow h$ converges in $L_2$

how to show: $g=h$ almost everywhere

Attempt:
convergent in $L_1$ implies convergent in $L_2$. then by triangle inequality g-h converges to zero in $L_2$. convergent in $L_2$ implies convergent in measure. so $\mu\lbrace x: |g-h|>\alpha\rbrace$ goes to zero. does this imply our conclusion?

Comment: In general, $L^2$-convergence does not imply $L^1$-convergence. Do you consider a finite measure space?

Comment: yes, in finite. but doesnt $L^1$ convergence imply $L^2$ convergence

Comment: No, actually it is the other way round: $L^2$-convergence implies $L^1$-convergence. (This means that, basically, your proof still works. If you know that $$\int |f| \, d\mu = 0$$ implies $f=0$ ($\mu$)-a.e. you don't even have to talk about convergence in measure.)

Comment: is it possible to show the result if we don't have finite m.space?

Comment: Yes. If $f_n \to g$ in $L^p$ for some $p \geq 1$, then there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ such that $f_{n_k} \to g$ almost everywhere. Similarly, we can find a subsequence which converges (almost everywhere) to $h$. Now the claim follows from the uniqueness of the limit.

Comment: Two subsequence can converge different limits if the sequence has no limit. In this case we don't have any information on covergence of the sequence except in $L^p$ which only gives the fact that there is a subsequnce converges a.e.
So how do you use the uniqueness property when we can't talk about the limit of the sequence itself? I do not understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need two ingredients:

1. If a sequence $(f_n)_n$ converges in some $L^p$ then there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$  that converges almost everywhere.
2. A subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit.

Now, since $(f_n)_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^1$ then, (by 1.), there there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$  that is simply convergent to $g$ on $\Bbb{R}\setminus {\cal N}$, where ${\cal N}$ is $\mu$-negligable.
Since $(f_n)_n$ converges to $h$ in $L^2$, the subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ converges also, (by 2.) to $h$. Thus, using (1.) again, there is a subsequence $(f_{n_{k_r}})_r$ that is 
simply convergent to $h$ on $\Bbb{R}\setminus {\cal N}'$ where ${\cal N}'$ is $\mu$-negligable.
Now, for every $x$ in $\Bbb{R}\setminus ({\cal N}\cup{\cal N}')$, the sequence
$(f_{n_{k_r}}(x))_r$ converges to $h(x)$ and to $g(x)$ (as subsequence of $(f_{n_k}(x))_k$).
This proves that $g(x)=h(x)$ for every $x$ in $\Bbb{R}\setminus ({\cal N}\cup{\cal N}')$,
which is the desired conclusion.